# How to add flags to messages.sendMessage call to Telegram REST API call via URL

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am using very simple Telegram bot, that only sends messages, so to make it simple I only send POST request to sendMessage API via Python's requests library. But I cannot understand how to add flags to this call properly.
Basically I only need to add no_webpage and silent flags.

Is this even possible? I really don't want to use more advanced tech, because this will require registering an app as well, and its just an overkill.

My URL looks like this:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=CHAT&parse_mode=HTML&flags=1
```

I send text in the post body (not sure if it's even helpful, because of the 4096 symbols limit)

I tried to bit-encode flags field, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean with 'no_webpage' flags? Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I do mean to add flag no_webpage, that is described in the API here: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong documentation, the link in your comment refers to the [core-api](https://core.telegram.org/api#tdlib--build-your-own-telegram), since you are using a BOT, you should only look at the [BOT API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods).

If you look at the [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method, you'll see the parameter:

> `link_preview_options`
>
> Link preview generation options for the message

Check the [`LinkPreviewOptions`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#linkpreviewoptions) for all the options, seems like you're looking for the `is_disabled` flag.

---

An [python](/questions/tagged/python) example showing how to pass this:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse
import requests

url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY-Bot0TOKEN>/sendMessage"

query_string = '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'chat_id': 12345,
    'text': 'Hello this is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77986367/how-to-add-flags-to-messages-sendmessage-call-to-telegram-rest-api-call-via-url)',
    'parse_mode': 'markdown',
    'link_preview_options': json.dumps({
        'is_disabled': True
    })
})
response = requests.request("POST", url + query_string)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

The first message is with `false` and the second with `true` on `is_disabled`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked, their documentation is hard to navigate.